# Media query does not hide an image

Tags: html, css, media-queries, media

I want to hide my site for screens below 800px width.

```
<body>
...
<img id="elephC" src="img/eleph.gif" alt="img">
...
<div id='minW'>
qadenzaClub
<br>
<div id='minW_red'>min 800 px<br>screen width required</div>
</div>
...
</body>
```

css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:799px){
body * {
 display:none;
}
#minW, #minW div, #minW br{
    display:block;
}
}
```

Resizing the window on 799px, everything inside the `body` tag is hidden, EXCEPT the `elephC` image !  (animated gif).

`minW` and children divs are displayed properly.

I tested the markup and css on W3C Validation Service - it's ok.

Comment: Please recreate this in a http://jsfiddle.net  the code seems fine and should work

Comment: Yeah, this JSFiddle seems to play nicely (no changes): http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/F6SQH/

Comment: It's probably something else in your CSS is overriding the `display:none` property. Try using the `!important` keyword or figure out which rule is being chosen instead (eg, using Chrome's DevTools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** 
1. The `!important` keyword prevents another rule from overriding the `display` property.

```
  @media only screen and (max-width:799px){
            body *{
             display:none !important;
            }
      #minW, #minW div, #minW br{
        display:block !important;
      }
 }
```

its working now [Look](http://jsfiddle.net/KR2JN/) for yourself :)

Comment: Why would you use this rather than what OP already has? Please explain.

Comment: 1- instead of hiding all the elemnts then showing the divs he want why dont we hide just the element we want to be hidden .
2- the !important keyword prevent any override to the display proprety that might be showing the img

Comment: Yup. That's what I want to see in your answer, bud. :)

Comment: I just realized the latter case may fail since the elements we want to *show* are also being selected by `body *`.

Comment: @bonaca you should look for the root of the cause instead of doing this important override

Comment: Now it works, using `!important` twice. But why I must use them. Which rule I need to override ?

Comment: for the first !important we were overriding someting in your css or previous declartions.
for the second one we were overriding the previous !important for those only ( #minW, #minW div, #minW br)